# In MongoDb, how do you use $in to match against values stored in an array variable

Tags: mongodb

Take the collection:

```
{
    "event_type" : "ENTRY",
    "DateTime" : ISODate("2024-02-08T00:00:00.000+0000"),
},
{
    "event_type" : "ENTRY",
    "DateTime" : ISODate("2024-02-09T00:00:00.000+0000"),
},
{
    "event_type" : "ENTRY",
    "DateTime" : ISODate("2024-02-10T00:00:00.000+0000"),
},
{
    "event_type" : "DELETE",
    "DateTime" : ISODate("2024-02-10T00:00:00.000+0000"),
},
{
    "event_type" : "DELETE",
    "DateTime" : ISODate("2024-02-24T00:00:00.000+0000"),
}
```

What I want to do is find all of the entries that match a date in any delete

My shell script:

```
var col = db.getCollection("test_collection");

var delete_dates = col.find({"event_type" : "DELETE" }).map(function(x) {return  x.DateTime});
col.find({"event_type" : "ENTRY", "DateTime" : {$in : delete_dates}});
```

I can see the array delete_dates has two values, as expected, and they are both "ISODate" type. However, the final line returns nothing.

If I replace `{$in : delete_dates}` with `{$in : [ ISODate("2024-02-10T00:00:00.000+0000"), ISODate("2024-02-24T00:00:00.000+0000")]}` it works as expected, and I get a single result back.

So what am I messing up? How can I use that array in the $in part of my match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to do it in a single (atomic) aggregation query:

1. `$group` by the `DateTime` and keep the original `ENTRY` event and the `_id` of the delete events
2. Keep only documents which have both.
3. Format

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$group: {
      _id: "$DateTime",
      entry: {$push: {$cond: [{$eq: ["$event_type", "ENTRY"]}, "$$ROOT", "$$REMOVE"]}},
      delete: {$push: {$cond: [{$eq: ["$event_type", "DELETE"]},  "$_id", "$$REMOVE"]}}
  }},
  {$match: {"delete.0": {$exists: true}, "entry.0": {$exists: true}}},
  {$replaceRoot: {newRoot: {$first: "$entry"}}}
])
```

See How it works on the [mongoDB playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/IHLnQwsiJtj)

Comment: Thanks! This did the trick. I still have a lot to learn about mongodb